# Sum of all the elements in an array in less than O(N2)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have an Array A with size N. I want to make a new array of size N*N such that my new Array B will be as follow with Time Complexity less than Ω(N2):

```
For A[0..N-1] ,
B= {A[0]+A[0],,A[0]+A[1], A[0]+A[2], ……., A[1]+A[0], A[1]+A[1],A[1]+A[2], ……., A[N-1]+A[0], A[N-1]+A[1],..., A[N-1]+A[N-1]}.
```

Example:

```
A={1,2}
```

The sequence B is `{ A1+A1, A1+A2, A2+A1, A2+A2 } = {2,3,3,4}.` 
Please provide me the code for this.

Comment: B has `N*N` elements. Every element must be assigned, which takes at least some amount of time. You want to do this in less than `O(N*N)` time. Do you see a problem here?

Comment: I've edited the tags on your question, since it's not at all (as stated) about C nor C++.

Comment: Yes.I have tried 2 for loops so clearly it won't work. Is there any solution to make it in O(N) instead of O(N*N)

Comment: In theory, you could recognise that there are sums evaluated more than once, e.g., `A1+A2 = A2+A1`, but the number of *unique* sums is still has an O(N^2) bound. Consider the ratio of unique sums to repeated sums as N -> infinity.

Comment: @BrettHale Knowing that some elements of an array are repeated does not provide a way to populate the entire array in fewer array writes. It might mean whatever would be done with the array later doesn't really need the entire array, but that's a different question.

Comment: @aschepler - you are confusing the complexity of the *algorithm* with memory access, as are some of the other answers. As you say, it is not about C, C++.

Comment: @BrettHale I have not seen any definitions of time complexity that include anything similar to "make an array with given values" where the time for doing that thing is not proportional to the number of array elements.

Comment: @Piyu Putting on my guessing hat, most likely you were given some task X and asked to do it with some time limit (either theoretical or measured). You decided that in order to do task X, you would have the code create this array `B`. But that took too much time, and now we're saying no, this *cannot* be done in less than `O(N*N)` time.  It might still be possible to do task X in less than `O(N*N)` time, but if so, it will need a different approach which doesn't require storing `N*N` or more values.

Comment: @aschepler Sure. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "please provide me the code" is considered a no-go on SO.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done.

Populating an array of size *N*<sup>2</sup> involves at least *N*<sup>2</sup> writes, so it requires *Ω*(*N*<sup>2</sup>) time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem description example isn't consistent.

You provided:

```
For A[0..N-1] ,
B= {A[0]+A[1], A[0]+A[2], ……., A[1]+A[0], A[1]+A[2], ……., A[N-1]+A[0], A[N-1]+A[1],..., A[N-1]+A[N-1]}
```

If you observe, the number isn't getting added to itself. A[0] doesn't seem to be added with A[0] and A[1] doesn't seem to be added with A[1]. But again, A[n-1] seems to be added with A[n-1] at the end. I think it should've been A[n]+A[n-1] to follow the pattern. Also, in this case, the size of B would've been N*(N-1).

Again, the example that you gave doesn't match the problem description. In your example, you seem to add the numbers to itself.

```
A={1,2}
The sequence B is { A1+A1, A1+A2, A2+A1, A2+A2 } = {2,3,3,4}.
```

Please update the question and correct the example or the problem description and it'll be helpful if you can provide the text description of the problem alongside explanation with numerical examples.

Comment: can you pleasse provide the code if you understood my problem?

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried this way.**

```
long long a[n],i,j,b[n*n],cnt=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>a[i];
        int l=0,r=n-1;
        for(i=0,j=n-1;;)
        {
            if(i!=j)
            {
                b[i]=a[i]+a[l];
                b[j]=a[j]+a[r];
            }
            if(i==j)
            {
                b[i]=a[i]+a[l];
            }
            l++;
            r--;
            cnt++;
            if(l==n-1 && r==0)
            {
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            if(cnt%n==0)
            {
                l=0;
                r=n-1;
            }
            if(cnt==n*n || i>j)break;
```

Answer (score -1):

If every array element is to form a sum with every other element, you are basically forming a mirror image of data diagonally.

A1+A2 will give you the same result as A2+A1, hence you only need to loop through approximately (n*n)/2 times.

**Sample code:**

```
int[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[][] matrix = new int[r][c];

for(int x=0; x<=r; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<r-x; y++){
        matrix[x][y] = nums[x] + nums[y];       //update 1st diagonal half
        matrix[r-x-1][c-y-1] = matrix[x][y];    //update the next half (follow 1st half)
    }
```

Comment: Which is still Omega(n^2).

Comment: No, wait a minute, we don't have to loop n^2 times. If assigning values are constant and we ignore constant. It will not be O(n^2) because we don't have to loop n^2 times in this scenario. We can stop after looping approximately (n^2)/2 times.

Comment: Scaling constants are ignored.  Doing a constant amount of work *per operation* still requires work proportional to the number of times the operation is performed, regardless of what that per-op constant is.

Comment: If you understood my problem statement then can you please provide code for this?

Comment: @Piyu See my code. This will loop less than n^2 times, but I hope someone with excellent understanding of big O notation can let me know what is my big O efficiency in this case.

Comment: It's still Omega(n^2).

Comment: Simple, time complexity is based on how many operation being executed. You definitely need N*N writes, no matter how you put it.